# how to retrieve data from database using flex code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I want to display the values coming from database in a datagrid using flex. Here is my code. I am using webservice. I have database values from `application1_initializeHandler()` method. How to fetch these values into onResult() method and perform databinding? I want code for `onResult()` function and data binding. Please help..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;


            protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                AreasOfWestBengal.loadWSDL();
                var s:String = "SELECT * FROM [CSFTestNew].[dbo].[AreasOfWestBengal]";
                var t:AsyncToken = AreasOfWestBengal.GetRec("[AreasOfWestBengal]", s, "1", "SQLExpress");
                t.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault, t));
            }

            protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent, token:Object=null):void
            {


            }

            protected function onFault(event:FaultEvent, token:Object=null):void
            {
                trace(event.fault.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:WebService id="AreasOfWestBengal" wsdl="https://www.geoviewer8.com/gv8webservices/CSF_NewGVOConfig/GVOConfig.asmx?wsdl"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:DataGrid x="197" y="83" width="348" height="216">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Areas" dataField="Areas"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="SubAreas" dataField="SubAreas"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>  

</s:Application>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set a data provider (like an *ArrayCollection*) for your *mx:DataGrid* as its *dataProvider* attribute - see the [*Passing Data to a DataGrid Control* section here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html) for an example.

Now, when your *onResult* function executes, you probably want to first clear out your data provider (remove any rows from your *DataGrid*) - if the data source is an *ArrayCollection*, you would use the *removeAll* method.  Now obtain the actual web service call result from the [*ResultEvent*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html) parameter (in your code, it is `event.result`).  You need to know the data type of this result value (it should be some kind of list data structure) so that you can figure out how to add its elements into the *DataGrid's* data provider as rows of the grid.  For example, if your data provider is an [*ArrayCollection*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html#methodSummary), you can add each element of `event.result` into this *ArrayCollection* using its *addItem* method.  If `event.result` implements the *IList* interface, you could add all rows into the data provider using the *addAll* method of *ArrayCollection*.  Make sure that the objects that you add into the data provider as the rows conform to your *mx:DataGridColumns* - i.e. these objects need to have *Areas* and *SubAreas* properties so that their values will be displayed in these columns.

Here is a [web service-specific *DataGrid* example from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html).

```
protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent, token:Object=null):void
{
     // Assuming the grid's data provider is an ArrayCollection

     // (1) clear existing table rows
     dataProvider.removeAll();

     // (2) add the new rows from event.result into dataProvider 
     // using dataProvider.addAll(event.result) if possible or one at a time
     // using dataProvider.addItem(...)
     dataProvider.addAll(event.result);

     // An alternative to the above would be to replace the dataProvider 
     // of your grid with event.result if it is a compatible data type
     //       AreasOfWestBengal.dataProvider = event.result;
}
```